# Switching Rails session store from cookie to cache: InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited management of a rails site which uses a cookie-based session store. I've been receiving errors because the cookies are too big ("Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters.") and so am trying to switch to a cache-based session store. (Aside: This is primarily due to an access token for Microsoft Graph which is 1,798 characters. The resultant cookie is 3,000-some characters. Does that seem right? Even if the cookie were only 1,798-ish though, I think I'd want to store that on the server, right?)

Everything I've been reading has suggested that this switch should be easy: change the session store settings from `:cookie_store` to `:cache_store`. Here's the new `session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_site_session'
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_access_token'
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_workbook_id'
```

After doing this I now see the '_workbook_id' cookie in my browser drop in size to 44, so that looks good. However, I'm now unable to log in to the site. When I do so, I get the error: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /login`. I've traced the authentication process a bit and verified that the issue (I think) is that Rails runs `valid_authenticity_token` in `request_forgery_protection.rb` with non-matching tokens. I'm not sure why though, or where to go next though. I admit I'm a Rails novice tinkering with things I don't yet understand.

Note: I'm also seeing a bunch of exceptions when I make the login request:

```
Exception raised: [LoadError]: cannot load such file -- devise/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [LoadError]: cannot load such file -- devise/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [LoadError]: No such file to load -- devise/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError]: Missing helper file helpers/devise/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [LoadError]: cannot load such file -- users/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [LoadError]: cannot load such file -- users/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [LoadError]: No such file to load -- users/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError]: Missing helper file helpers/users/sessions_helper.rb
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Session
Exception raised: [ArgumentError]: no receiver is available
Exception raised: [ArgumentError]: no receiver is available
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Users::Session
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Session
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Session
Exception raised: [ArgumentError]: no receiver is available
Exception raised: [ArgumentError]: no receiver is available
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Users::Session
Exception raised: [NameError]: uninitialized constant Session
```

These show up with both cookie stores and cache stores though, so I don't *think* that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it expires. Try to update `session_store.rb` file

```
# config/init../session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
    :key => '_localhost_session', 
    :compress => true,
    :pool_size => 10,
    :expire_after => 1.year
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! `compress` drops the cookie size to 410. I've failed to find documentation on those extra options. Do you know where I could look?

Comment: @Trygve somehow could'nt find also, if dnt wanna compress, just set it `false` or remove it.

Comment: Compress is what makes this work, for me, as it dramatically reduces the cookie size. I'm more curious about `pool_size`: what does that do? And why would I ever _not_ want `compress`? Just curious really: if it works, it works!

Comment: @Trygve finally found https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores

Comment: Looks like that's the best we have. It still makes no mention of cookie_store or pool_size, and says that compress defaults to true, which isn't what I'm seeing. Baffling. Thanks for looking though!

Comment: Unfortunately, on further testing this turns out not to solve the problem. I think I was accidentally testing pages in a different order. The page that creates the 4,000 character cookie still does that, and if I create that cookie before the login, the login fails because it tips the cookie over the 4096 limit. Compress does indeed default to true, and `pool_size` and `expire_after` don't appear to have an effect on the cookie size.